# Send additional parameters in a google maps event function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I had this, works fine:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(event) {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setMap(null);
    marker.solucionado = true;
    cant_markers--;
    cant_solucionados++;
});
```

But I want to do this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', deleteMarker);

function deleteMarker(marker) {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setMap(null);
    marker.solucionado = true;
    cant_markers--;
    cant_solucionados++;
});
```

`marker` it's currently out of the scope, there is a way to send the  marker object as a parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`marker` isn't out of scope, `marker` **is the scope** where the handler will be executed.

The scope of a handler added via `addListener` is always the object where the listener has been added to(first argument of `addListener`, it's `marker` in your code)

Simply use `this` to access the marker inside the handler:

```js
function initialize() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
      zoom: 1
    }),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: map.getCenter()
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', deleteMarker);

}

function deleteMarker() {
  this.setMap(null);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

However, when you wan't to pass additional arguments to the handler it's possible too, use [`deleteMarker.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)(or [`deleteMarker.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply))

Example:

```js
function initialize() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(1, 2),
      zoom: 1
    }),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: map.getCenter()
    }),
    var1 = "it ",
    var2 = "work's";
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick',
    function(e) {
      deleteMarker.call(this, //the scope of the handler...the marker
        e, //the original event
        var1, //additonal argument
        var2 //another argument
      );
    }
  );

}

function deleteMarker(event, v1, v2) {
  this.setMap(null);
  alert(v1 + v2 + '@' + event.latLng)
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to build your app with generic functions for such a general action as deleting a marker. At some moment you might want to delete a list of a markers simultaneously or delete a marker for other reason than a righ-click. For that, it's a better practice to create a function that handle all (or most of) situations than repeating your code.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(e){
    deleteMarkers([marker]);
});

function deleteMarkers(markers) {
    for (var i=0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
});
```

see doc: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventArguments

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have overridden `marker` with the event argument.

try this...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', deleteMarker);

function deleteMarker(event) {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setMap(null);
    marker.solucionado = true;
    cant_markers--;
    cant_solucionados++;
});
```

if you need to pass multiple parameters, you can do so as such...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(event) {
  deleteMarker(event, marker);
});

function deleteMarker(event, marker) {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setMap(null);
    marker.solucionado = true;
    cant_markers--;
    cant_solucionados++;
});
```

Comment: but based on the code posted, you just need to change `function deleteMarker(marker) {` to `function deleteMarker(event) {`